# Why does Google Plus email my whole family when I share a post?

Tags: google, google-plus

I frequently share photos from Instant Upload with my Family circle (which has 7 people in it).  Every time I do this, I make sure that `Also send email to Family` is unchecked.  However, every time, I hear back from a few people that they got an email notifying them about my post.  I checked my wife's account, and in addition to the email she received, she has a notification that I shared my post *directly* with her.

Why is this?  I don't want to spam my whole family every time I post.  Is this a known issue, and is there any way that I can work around it?

I have submitted feedback to Google regarding this and have received no response.

Comment: Do you mean that they are receiving TWO email? One that you have shared something, and one that says you're shared something *directly*?

Comment: @OnenOnlyWalter, no I mean that she's receiving one email, and when I look at her Google+ notification, it says that I shared a post with her directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your family will need to edit their email notifications settings. This can be done by going to:

*Google+* → *Settings* (Gear) → Edit your **Receive Notifications** options

[image]

Each person will have to do this though, since the notifications are controlled on their side. This will allow them to continue to receive notifications in the top right (red square) but not in their inbox.

Comment: I have easy access to my wife's Google+ account, and can confirm that she does have email checked if someone "Shares a post with me directly".  I guess my problem is - why are my posts being shared directly with everyone in my family circle?  I'm not tagging anyone when I post, and I simply share the post with my entire Family circle.

Comment: Sharing to a circle **is** sharing with them directly. As long as you have added a name to your circle, they will continue to be notified. Sharing with someone *indirectly* means either sharing publicly or to your "Extended Circles"

Comment: Really?  Well that would certainly clarify it - so any time you share a post with just your circles, everyone in your circles will be notified?  Seems pretty broken, but I guess I'll just have to live with it.

Comment: IMO it's not broken, just up to the receiving user to decide whether they want to get email notifications for things shared with circles. It certainly helps me to know when people are sharing with me.

Comment: It should not be up to the receiving user. When I post, and I uncheck the box that says Send Notifications or whatever, g+ should *NOT* send notifications!

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that all your family members are not on Google+. If a person is not on Google+, they may receive an email notifying them of your post and inviting them to Google+. Secondly, you cannot restrict email notifications to your family members (if they are on Google+). They would need to change their email notification settings to restrict such notifications.